# change from five boxes to the same length rectangle using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi All: I have a code snippet below which works beautifully and was provided by someone on this list to me a while back.  But now I want to change it so that I draw one long rectangle instead of the adjacent five boxes. The text inside the rectangle should just be at the far right of it and could say `$Y^{*}_{whatever}$`. I'm thinking that I need to define a rectnode instead of a squared node with different things in it.  But I don't understand how to make it the same length as the length of the boxes and in the same position. "minimum size" currently inside the definition of squarednode isn't making sense to me.

EDIT:

I have edited this question by including a handwritten drawing in order to express the fact that I need the rectangles to line up with the horizontal axis as shown. So, the first rectangle travels from 0 to 5. The second rectangle travels from 1 to 6, etc all the way to the 6th rectangle travelling from 5 to 10.

Also, all the rectangles should be the same width and length even though it may not seem that way by the picture. I also don't need a y-axis.

Thanks and I'm sorry for not being clearer the first time.

[image: Desired output]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
squarednode/.style={draw=black, minimum size=9.9mm},
y=1.5cm
]
  
%boxes

    \draw (0.5, 5.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{1}^{*}$};
    \draw (1.5, 5.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{2}^{*}$};
    \draw (2.5, 5.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{3}^{*}$};
    \draw (3.5, 5.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{4}^{*}$};
    \draw (4.5, 5.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{5}^{*}$};
            
    \draw (1.5, 4.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{2}^{*}$};
    \draw (2.5, 4.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{3}^{*}$};
    \draw (3.5, 4.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{4}^{*}$};
    \draw (4.5, 4.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{5}^{*}$};
    \draw (5.5, 4.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};

    \draw (2.5, 3.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{3}^{*}$};
    \draw (3.5, 3.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{4}^{*}$};
    \draw (4.5, 3.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{5}^{*}$};
    \draw (5.5, 3.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (6.5, 3.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    
    \draw (3.5, 2.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{4}^{*}$};
    \draw (4.5, 2.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{5}^{*}$};
    \draw (5.5, 2.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (6.5, 2.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (7.5, 2.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    
    \draw (4.5, 1.5) node[squarednode] {$X_{5}^{*}$};
    \draw (5.5, 1.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (6.5, 1.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (7.5, 1.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (8.5, 1.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    
    \draw (5.5, 0.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (6.5, 0.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (7.5, 0.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (8.5, 0.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
    \draw (9.5, 0.5) node[squarednode,dashed] {0};
                    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: would you like to add a handdrawn sketch of the desired output

Comment: M. Al Jumally. Is there a way to include the pdf of the output ? I have the pdf but I don't know how to include it. thanks.

Comment: M. Al. Jumally: I managed to write code like this and it works !!!                              \draw  (0.0,5.5) rectangle (5.0,6.0);   but then, I try to put text at the end in order to put it inside the rectangle and that gives me an error.   \draw  (0.0,5.5) rectangle (5.0,6.0)   {$Y^{*}_{11:00-11:05}$};

Comment: So, my question is: Is there a way to make a rectangle and then specify that one wants some text at the far end of the rectangle ? thanks so much.

Comment: You can take a screenshot of the pdf and paste it into the question. I am sure it will be much easier for you to explain and for others to answer :)

Comment: @M. Al. Jumally: I managed ( sort of ) to link to a hand-drawn picture if you click on the 1 in my edited email. Thanks and I'm apologize for not being clearer the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the options of
[Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551827/167081), here is a complete and short solution to your request (note, the red dashed lines are just there if you needed them). There are two types of shapes: `rectangleNode` and `dashedSquared`. `rectangleNode` will have the text at far right whereas `dashedSquared` will be an empty square. The idea is simple, we draw the rectangle first and assign it a name (say, `n1`), then draw the square (without assigning it a name) and use `right=0pt of n1` to position it correctly. The `0pt` is how far [pt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) units away from the rectangle. I attached two outputs: the vertical line between them is solid and dashed. For the dashed version, we just need to also add `fill=white, right=-\pgflinewidth of n1`. The fill is needed to overdraw the vertical line of the rectangle. The `\pgflinewidth` is the width of the line (which is really tiny but exact :)).

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        rectangleNode/.style={
            draw=black, align=right, 
            minimum width=10em, minimum height=2.5em, 
            outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt, 
            text width=9em,%change size to adjust the text position
        },
        dashedSquared/.style={
        draw=black,dashed, minimum height=2.5em, minimum width=2em
        },
        every node/.style={outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt}
    ]
    \node[rectangleNode] (n1) at (0,0) {$X_{1}^{*}$};%reference point
    %\node[dashedSquared, right=0pt of n1]{};%reference point
    % uncomment the previous line and comment out the next if you want solid
    % vertical line between the rectangle and square.
    \node[dashedSquared, fill=white, right=-\pgflinewidth of n1]{};

    % Comment the following three lines if you will use the dash pattern.
        \foreach \x in {2,...,6}{% 6 is the number of boxes in total
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevNode}{\x - 1}
             \node[
             rectangleNode, 
             right = 2em of n\prevNode, % horizontal dist between
                                                          % rectangles is 2em units
             yshift=-0.5em,             % vertical dist between 
                                                 %rectangles is 0.5em units (negative)
             below of = n\prevNode,
             ] (n\x){$Y_{\x}^{*}$};
             \ifthenelse{\x=6}{
                % last rectangle, don't add the dashed box (do nothing).
             }{
                % not the last rectangle, append the square.
                 \node[dashedSquared, right=0pt of n\x]{};%reference point
                % comment out the previous line and uncomment next if you want dashed
                % vertical line between the rectangle and square.
                %\node[dashedSquared, fill=white, right=-\pgflinewidth of n\x]{};
             }
        }
        % Adding labels and ticks. Create label0 as 
        % starting point and then use a for loop.
        \node[red, below=19em of n1.south west](label0){$0$};
        \draw[]([yshift=0.8em]label0.south) -- ([yshift=0.8em]label0.north);%ticks
        \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prevNode}{\x - 1}
            \node[red, right=1.5em of label\prevNode](label\x){$\x$};
            \draw[]([yshift=0.8em]label\x.south) -- ([yshift=0.8em]label\x.north);%ticks
             %\draw (\i-3,-7)--++(90:3mm) node[below]{\i};
        }
        % Adding red dashed lines.
         \foreach \x in {1,...,6}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 1}
            \draw[red, dashed] (n\x.south west) -- ([yshift=1em]label\label.north);
        }
        % X axis line
        \draw[blue]([yshift=0.5em, xshift=-0.5em]label0.north west) --
         ([yshift=0.5em]label0.north west -| label10.north east);
        % Y axis line
        \draw[blue, thick] ([xshift=-0.5em]n1.north west) -- 
        ([xshift=-0.5em]n1.north west|-label0.north);
        % X axis label
        \node[above right =0.6em and 1em of label10.center]{min};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Simple breakdown of the code:

- `\prevNode` is just an integer which will temporarily be (and in order) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
- `-0.5em` is the vertical distance between the nodes (the comment stated `1em` but should have stated `-0.5em` instead (sorry!) and now corrected). It needs to be negative since we are placing the first node at the top, hence, the second node and onward needs to be placed below.
- `(n\x)` is appending `n` and the value of `x` (which is an integer), together. For example, if `\x` is `3`, then `(n\x)` evaluates to `(n3)`. The same goes to `n\prevNode`, it appends `n` with the value of `\prevNode` (`\prevNode` is also an integer).
- Furthermore, you might be able to see that `n\prevNode` is nₓ₋₁ (x-1ᵗʰ node) and `n\x` is nₓ (xᵗʰ node).
- Lastly, the node `(n1)` is hardcoded since we need to have a starting point. So, the for loop starts at 2, and refers to the previous node `n\prevNode` = `n1` and create the new node `(n\x)` = `(n2)`. Then, the loop continues to 3 and previous node is `n2` where current node is `n3` and so on.

Comment: It looks great. I will print out and try to comprehend. Thanks so much.

Comment: Jumally: I've gone through some tutorials so my knowledge is a little better but not much. I sort of get it but I definitely couldn't do it myself. But,  if you can answer the following questions, it's much appreciated. 1) Is prevnode a macro that always refers to the previous node ? 2) if yshift = -0.5em then why is the distance 1em ?  What does the n mean in n\prevNode and in (n\x). Thanks.

Comment: AI Jumally. Apologies for writing your name incorrectly in the previous comment.

Comment: M Al Jumally: That was a great explanation. My only question is by putting (n\x) {$Y_{\x}^{*}$}, I think you're creating a new node. Is there a location where the new node is being created ? Thanks. I learned a lot from your code and explanation. But I needed both :).

Comment: Al Jumally: I know that I'm getting greedy but since I actually understand your code now, would you mind making a horizontal axis that has the same alignment as my picture. Ignasio made one but I'm not sure what will happen if I take his and put it in your code. Somehow, I don't think that's going to work but I'll try it and see what happens !!!! Thanks.

Comment: The node created in the for loop can be seen as the following: `\node[some attributes](nameOfNode){some text}`. That `nameOfNode` is needed so we can refer to it the next time we execute the for loop to say we will create a new node now, but where will it be place? well, it will be places just a little bit below `nameOfNode` (which is the node we created in the previous time we looped). Is that clearer?

Comment: nice. gotcha. that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: yes. I tried it by taking Ignasio's code and just putting it in but that makes the x-axis be right on top of the last rectangle and aligned with it. Thanks. Oh, Ignasio's axis aligns exactly as my picture shows but I don't understand his code.

Comment: M. Al. Jumaily: It looks amazing. I will print out and study both your solution and Ignasio's solution carefully. To me, try to learn tikz  is kind of akin to trying to learn a new programming language. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @M.AI Jumally : I kind of understand what you did but wanted to make one last change and was unsuccessful. What I want to do is take the exact picture that you have made but add a dashed box to the end of each rectangle that spans 1 minute. So, nothing is different ( The Y's stay in there at their same position ) except for  the addition of a dashed box. You've done a lot for me already so, if you're ever in NYC, I'd like to show my appreciation. My email address is my name with a 2 on the end of it and the server is the famous company that starts with a G !!!!!!  Thank you so much.

Comment: @markleeds, I have updated the answer, have a look :)! I appreciate your kind gesture! I will surely keep that offer in mind! Please let me know if this is sufficient :).

Comment: M. Al. Jumally: Thanks. It looks nice but not quite what I need. What you did was replace the last part of the rectangle with dashes. What I need is to actually ADD a dashed box ( so the rectangle becomes one unit longer )  but keep the Y's exactly where they are. Of course, a dashed box can't be added to the last rectangle on the very bottom but I don't need one there. Thanks so much and my gesture is really meant. It's amazing to me how generous people on this list are.

Comment: EXACTLY. I know that sounds weird. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the vertical line between them could be dashed. thanks so much.

Comment: @markleeds, sure! please see the edit :)

Comment: M. AI Jumally: That looks beautiful. Tomorrow I will try to take the dashed box off of the bottom rectangle because that one goes past the axis and I don't need it. You're REALLY TALENTED. I don't know what to say except thanks and, if I'm not able to take the dashes box off of the bottom rectangle, I'll bother you one last time. Thanks again.

Comment: M. Al Jumally: I just looked again and besides the dashed box on the bottom rectangle not being needed, I did notice one other thing. Is it possible to make the dashed boxes so that the end of the dashed box is aligned with the dark vertical line of the rectangle below it. In other words, the first dashed box should end at 6, the second dashed box should end at 7, the third dashed box should end at 8, the fourth dashed box should end at 9 and the fifth dashed box should end at 10. I hate to be so picky but it won't make sense unless that is the case.  Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: @markleeds, so Y_6 shouldn't have a dashed square?

Comment: M. Al Jumaily: correct. $Y^{*}_6$ doesn't need one. I was going to try to take care of that but I definitely won't be able to do the aligning that I described so maybe it's better if you do everything and then you can be done with my bothers :).

Comment: also, do comments at tex.stackexchange not allow latex ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110517/discussion-between-m-al-jumaily-and-mark-leeds).

Answer (score 2):

By default, node's contents are centered inside the node, but if you define some `text width`, then you can use `align` option to align the text to left or right.

An example:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm, text width=4cm , align=right] {Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you don't know desired dimensions, you can use `fit` library to define the new node. In this case, the text can be included with the `label` option.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, fit}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
squarednode/.style={draw=black, minimum size=9.9mm},
]
  
\matrix (A1) [matrix of math nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={squarednode, anchor=center}]
    {X_{1}^{*} & X_2^* & X_3^* & X_4^* & X_5^*\\};

%Use inner nodes coordinates because matrix node is larger.
\node[fit=(A1-1-1.north west) (A1-1-5.south east), inner sep=0pt, label={[left]0:$Y^{*}_{\text{whatever}}$}, draw, below=3mm of A1] {};
                    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: solution to real question

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1.5cm]
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,5}
    \node[minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm, 
        anchor=north west, text width=4.5cm, align=right, draw] at
        (\i,-\i) {$Y_\i$};
\draw (0,-6) -- ++(0:10.5) node[right] {min};
\foreach \i in {0,...,10}
    \draw ([yshift=2mm]\i,-6)--++(-90:4mm) node[below]{\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: all I can say is wow and thanks. this is all new to me so much appreciated. I'll go over it carefully. oh, as far as trying ( emphasis on trying !!! LOL ) to learn this material, I imagine you recommend the over 1000 page documentation.  that seems to be what everyone points to. thanks again.

Comment: just a heads up that although your solutions were great, I didn't explain my problem clearly enough. So, I edited my question and included a drawing. I'm sorry for not being clear the first time. I'm also trying to understand your solutions (and possibly modify for my problem ) but it's not easy. I was trying to learn the tikz basics so adding fit on top of that is another level of complexity. Thanks for anything you can do.

Comment: @markleeds I've edited the answer with a solution for your new question. Hope it helps. About the manual, of course it's worth to read it and of course it's intimidating. But you can start with initial tutorials. They are easy to read and are a complete introduction to Tikz. After that you will know a lot about tikz and just need to read particular topics in the rest of the book.

Comment: yes. I think going through smaller tutorials, is better for me. I have found some and am going through them. Still, there's no easy way to learn this material and some people are just plain better than others ( from birth I guess ). Thank you for the edit. I will keeps yours checked but try to understand both. That's easier said than done of course.

Comment: Hi:  I've gone through some tikz tutorials but I still don't feel terribly knowledgeable. When you have a chance, if you could answer the following questions at your convenience, it would be really appreciated. 1)  In the first foreach loop why does the negative eye work ? I would think some of the y coordinates would be positive ? 2) The next to last statement draws the axis but what does the ++(0:10.5) node[right] {min}  do ?  The last foreach loop makes the horizontal coordinates but  the only part of the statement that I understand is the \i ,-6. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @markleeds 1) In the first foreach loop why does the negative eye work ?. I started the figure from top to bottom. Then every loop draws a rectangle one unit to the right and one unit below the previous one. Every vertical unit is 1.5cm. ++(0:10.5) indicates a relative increment from previous position. In this case move 10.5cm following a 0 degrees angle from actual pencil position. Same in last foreach. It draws 4mm long vertical lines (90:4mm) starting at a point 2mm below ([yshift=-2mm]) the reference (\i,-6) .

Comment: Thanks Ignasi. I will print out and read carefully. It's so appreciated.